# Using two characteristics in CoreBluetooth not working

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

Here is one problem I am facing when using `CoreBluetooth`.
Up to now I always used one service and one characteristic and all worked fine.
But here I must use two characteristics and things do not quite work.

What happens is that only the first characteristic is transmitted, not the second one.

Since there must be a mistake in my program, I try to put below all the relevant code, with some comments.
If someone thinks another part of the code is necessary to solve the issue, please let me know.

```
// Declarations relevant to the following code.
var cbPerifMngr:CBPeripheralManager!, mutaSRVC:CBMutableService!,
myCharacOne,myCharacTwo:CBMutableCharacteristic!

...................

// Code to update the CBMutableCharacteristic objects:
let strBuffOne = "abc123_my-information_1"
let strBuffTwo = "GHK678_my-information_2"
if cbPerifMngr.updateValue(Data(strBuffOne.utf8), for: myCharacOne,
                           onSubscribedCentrals: nil) {
    // All is OK.
    if cbPerifMngr.updateValue(Data(strBuffTwo.utf8), for: myCharacTwo,
                               onSubscribedCentrals: nil) {
        // All is OK.
    } else {
        print("1) For some reason, the CBPeripheralManager update was not performed in \(#function).")
    }
} else {
    print("2) For some reason, the CBPeripheralManager update was not performed in \(#function).")
}

...................

// Code for the CBPeripheralManagerDelegate protocol:

func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    print(#function)
    if peripheral.state == .poweredOn {
        mutaSRVC = CBMutableService(type: serviceDB_UUID, primary: true)
        myCharacOne = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: myChrcOne_UUID,
                                                    properties: [.read, .notify],
                                                    value: nil, permissions: .readable)
        myCharacTwo = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: myChrcTwo_UUID,
                                                    properties: [.read, .notify],
                                                    value: nil, permissions: .readable)
        mutaSRVC.characteristics = [myCharacOne,myCharacTwo]
        cbPerifMngr?.add(mutaSRVC)
    }
}

...................

// Code for the CBPeripheralDelegate protocol:

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService,
                error: Error?) {
    print(#function)
    if error != nil {
        print("Error in \(#function) :\n\(error!)")
    } else {
        // Here service.characteristics? contains 2 items.
        peripheral.setNotifyValue(true,
                                  for: (service.characteristics?[0])!)
        peripheral.setNotifyValue(true,
                                  for: (service.characteristics?[1])!)
    }
}


func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic,
                error: Error?) {
    print(#function)
    if error != nil {
        print("Error in \(#function) :\n\(error!)")
    } else {
        if let dataStr = String(data: characteristic.value!,
                                encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        print("dataStr:: \(dataStr)")
        }
    }
}
```

When running the code I can see in the debugger console that the last function (*peripheral:didUpdateValueFor:error*) is called for the first characteristic (myCharacOne), but not for the second one (myCharacTwo). That means, only the first part of the information is transmitted.

I hope some `CoreBluetooth` expert can see what is wrong in my code and give me some guidance.

Comment: What triggers the sending code on your peripheral side?  What output do you get from the peripheral app?

Comment: See in the code the part just below the comment: "// Code to update the CBMutableCharacteristic objects:". This answers your question. Beside I may need to tell that in this case the "peripheral app" and the "central app" are the same physical app (playing one role or the other depending on the use case). And as I mentioned it works when using one one characteristic.

Comment: The code shows how you send the data, but not what *triggers* the sending; i.e. What causes that code to execute.  Does your app print "1) For some reason, the CBPeripheralManager update was not performed in \(#function)." - you may find that you can't send the second characteristic immediately if the send queue is full; that is what a `false` return from `updateValue` indicates.  Have you implemented the `didUpdateNotificationStateFor` `CBPeripheralDelegate` method? Is notification being successfully enabled for both characteristics?

Comment: Have you checked that `service.characteristics?[0])` and `service.characteristics?[1])` are the right characteristics?

Comment: My app does not print "1) For some reason, the CBPeripheralManager update was not performed in (#function)." No, I did not implement the didUpdateNotificationStateFor CBPeripheralDelegate method.
For the last question, I have checked that service.characteristics? contains 2 elements, no more no less. And what triggers the sending is the push of a button. This part works since one of the characteristic is sent.

Comment: Then you should implement `didUpdateNotificationStateFor` and see if you are getting an error

Comment: I did so and I can see that it is executed, but it does not show any error. It does nothing though except displaying the error if there is one. Should it do anything special?

Comment: You should get two calls to that method, with `error` nil

Comment: Indeed after one call to peripheral:didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor:error;
I can see two calls to peripheral:didUpdateNotificationStateFor:error:;
both with error nil. But I still can't see any trace of the second characteristic.
...... On the other end, I just realized there is a problem in the code below the comment: "// Code to update the CBMutableCharacteristic objects:". It is probably what you were referring to in your first comment. I need to look closer.

Comment: In other words it prints:
"1) For some reason, the CBPeripheralManager update was not performed ..."
meaning the second cbPerifMngr.updateValue:for:onSubscribedCentrals is not performed smoothly.
I can see this when I look at the sending code, I think this is why I hadn't noticed it when you first asked me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185926/discussion-between-paulw11-and-michel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Core Bluetooth transmit queue has limited space.  If `updateValue` returns `false` then there is insufficient space in the transmit queue for the update.  Your program must queue further updates until you get a call to the [`peripheralManagerIsReady(toUpdateSubscribers)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanagerdelegate/1393248-peripheralmanagerisready) `CBPeripheralManagerDelegate` method.

Comment: I see. Then I will implement peripheralManagerIsReady:toUpdateSubscribers: and try from there. But does it still make sense to use several characteristics if I have to queue them in line?

Comment: I can't say.  It depends on why you are using two characteristics.  Normally each characteristic is a discrete piece of information; e.g. temperature and humidity or speed and direction.  If you are just sending a stream of bytes, you can just use one characteristic or an L2CAP channnel.

Comment: OK. Here I only use two because the length does not fit into one. What I am transferring is just a character string.

Comment: So it sounds like you should just use one characteristic and handle the queueing

Comment: OK. I will keep this in mind then. In the meanwhile, with all your tips it finally works.